# How to unescape a CDATA section using JAXB in a dynamic way

Tags: jaxb, escaping, cdata

I'm trying to make a section of my SOAP request look like this:

```
<![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><placeholder  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="WirelessEdgeInfo_v1_0.xsd"/>]]>
```

However, it looks like this after it has been escaped by underlying JAXB:

```
&lt;![CDATA[&lt;?xml version="1.0"
            encoding="UTF-8"?&gt; &lt;placeholder
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="WirelessEdgeInfo_v1_0.xsd"/&gt;]]&amp;gt
```

I have looked at numerous examples, such as using MOXy and also implementing a CharacterEscapeHandler adapter or XmlAdapter HOWEVER the problem is the same for ALL these implementations.  That is, it always comes down to this:

```
marshaller.setProperty(CharacterEscapeHandler.class.getName(),
                new XmlCharacterHandler());
```

Setting a property in the marshaller.

However, in my case, I am using annotations generated through WSImport to generate my Web Services code dynamically when I execute the client SOAP call.

**i.e. I do not have access to the marshaller object.**

SO for me, how can I unescape the CDATA section of a String variable I need to pass in if I cannot set any property on the marshaller type?

Can I somehow "hack" or trick JAXB to tell it not to escape CDATA values? Or can I use annotations or somehow dynamically indicate unescaping?

I tried the following Adapter via annotation but of course this did not work:

```
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=CDATAAdapter.class) //this is not working right now
protected String variableXmlContent;
```

variableXmlContent still ended up escaped.  I also tried unescaping variableXmlContent and setting it as an input value, but it still came out the same way, unescaped.

Answer (score 0):

An XML element value containing `<, >, &` is escaped by the marshaller using `&lt;, &gt;, &amp;`.

Thus, if the XML element should contain

```
<![CDATA[ ... ]]>
```

the result in the XML file will be

```
&lt;![CDATA[ ... ]]&gt;
```

I suspect that the text to be passed as an XML element is

```
<?xml version="1.0" ... v1_0.xsd"/>
```

Now if I had to write this by hand into an XML file, I'd write it into a "CDATA section", but a (JAXB) marshaller will simply treat those three characters as I described before, and that's it.

```
&lt;?xml version="1.0" ... v1_0.xsd"/&gt;
```

It is pointless to try and make any XML marshaller use the CDATA mechanism, and there is no such thing as a "CDATA value" requiring special treatment - so there is no such special treatment.